# Store int32 in int8 pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the below snippet, I define `foo` which is large enough to hold a 32-bit integer. However, when I try to store a 32-bit integer in `foo`, it does not fit.

```
int8_t * foo = malloc(sizeof(int32_t));
int32_t value = 300;
foo[0] = value;
printf("%i ", foo[0]); // 44
```

Is there some way to use up more elements to store the value instead of truncating it?

Comment: Why not use memcpy?

Comment: Yep, I should do that.

Answer (score 4):

`foo[0]` has type `int8_t`, so it is only big enough for 1 byte.

Although adjacent bytes (`foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]`) are available, the compiler doesn't know you intend to copy all 4 bytes when working with just `foo[0]`.

Instead:

```
*((int32_t*)foo) = 300;
```

Which says, *"Pretend that foo is the start of a 4-byte integer, then assign it the value 300"*.

Comment: Is this well-defined? (It seems like it might run afoul of the strict aliasing rule?)

Comment: Pointer pinning is discouraged. For type pinning use unions instead

Comment: @P__J__ could you expand on that? Sounds like a better option.

Comment: Note that `(int32_t*)foo` is not subject to alignment concerns as `foo` is aligned for `uint32_t` access. The result of `malloc()` is aligned for all basic types.

Comment: Yes, that is why `memcpy` seems like it may be a better option.

Comment: @ruakh Dynamically allocated memory works little different from normal types. Assignment changes effective type of the object to `int32_t`. It doesn't give free pass on strict aliasing though, for example, trying to read the value later with `*(int16_t*)foo` would still be invalid.